# preventing retain cycle with weak/unowned self in Realm notification block

Tags: swift, realm

I'm not sure whether I'm grasping the concept of unowned/weak in closures correctly yet, but I've been reading through the RealmSwift documentation and wanted to ask why the sample code in https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#interface-driven-writes does not implement `weak self`

```
token = collection.observe { changes in
    switch changes {
    case .initial:
        tableView.reloadData()
    case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
        // Query results have changed, so apply them to the UITableView
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.insertRows(at: insertions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }),
                             with: .automatic)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: deletions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)}),
                             with: .automatic)
        tableView.reloadRows(at: modifications.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }),
                             with: .automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    case .error(let error):
        // handle error
        ()
    }
}
```

but https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#object-notifications does

```
notificationToken = results.observe { [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
    guard let tableView = self?.tableView else { return }
    switch changes {
    case .initial:
        // Results are now populated and can be accessed without blocking the UI
        tableView.reloadData()
    case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
        // Query results have changed, so apply them to the UITableView
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.insertRows(at: insertions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }),
                                with: .automatic)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: deletions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)}),
                                with: .automatic)
        tableView.reloadRows(at: modifications.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }),
                                with: .automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    case .error(let error):
        // An error occurred while opening the Realm file on the background worker thread
        fatalError("\(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: it's just documentation, probably added by different people. the first one is more to-the-point without showing unnecessary concepts. Imho, documentation isn't always supposed to be copy-paste so don't read between the lines. Use your best judgement on when to capture `self` weakly.

Answer (score 1):

The first example doesn't use `weak/unowned`, because there are no any use of `self.`. But second example contains:

```
guard let tableView = self?.tableView else { return }
```

so, in this case you should use `weak/unowned`, because you capture `self` inside the closure.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. But, shouldn't the first example actually use `self.` inside the closure in order to reference tableView?